# HTML element on active event

Tags: javascript, performance, mouseevent, dom-events, opera

I want to measure the time between mousedown event and applying CSS active property without using any jQuery functions (pure Javascript). I found that there is onactive event but it is not supported by Opera (the browser on which I want to make this measurement). Actually this onactive event is supported only by IE (not sure which versions).

```
htmlElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){var timestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000; console.warn('mouse down ', timestamp)})

htmlElement.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(){var timestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000; console.info('highlighted ', timestamp)})
```

This 'DOMAttrModified' event doesn't report when a button becomes active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:active` is a CSS pseudo-class, not a DOM attribute or property. It isn't possible or feasible to measure the time between mouse down and the time the `:active` pseudo-class is set because of the single-threaded nature of GUI and code execution.  Basically, by the time the mouse event fires, CSS and GUI updates are already queued and no event fires for when `:active` is applied.

Still, I can't think of any valid reason for worrying about how long this process takes, you're probably better off forgetting about it and moving on.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't ask my questions correctly I want the time between mouse down and the end of rendering the changes that this ':active' pseudo class sets. For example I notices that if I use gradients rendering is much slower and this makes my GUI not very responsive.

Comment: @Nikolay: in that case, you may want to investigate the 0ms timeout using `window.postMessage` [as described here](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts).